# How does PostGIS store circles?

Tags: postgis, circle

I was reading this [answer by MikeT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10377/6052) to [Creating circle in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10352/115) which mentions that the following

```
SELECT ST_Area(geom)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(2 1, 1 2, 0 1, 1 0, 2 1))'::geometry)
) AS t(geom);
```

returns `3.14033115695475`. I tried it myself and it's true. He says it's only a rough approximation of pi? Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [PostGIS in Action, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1617291390) by Regina O. Obe and Leo S. Hsu. They mention this here,

> Why is a PostGIS 10-meter buffer of a point 312 and not 314 sq m?
>   If you do the calculation, a perfect 10-meter buffer will give you an area of 10*10*pi(), which is around 314 square meters. **The default buffer in PostGIS is a 32-sided polygon** (eight points approximate a quarter segment of a circle). You can make this more accurate by using the overloaded version of the ST_Buffer function that allows you to pass in the number of points used to approximate a quarter segment.

It seems that it's not just the `ST_Buffer` that makes this assumption. `ST_Area()` calls [`lwgeom_area_polygon`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/4b0ade47ebd194f97ddabb54ecdfa0c0243a3107/postgis/lwgeom_functions_basic.c#L270) which calls [`lwgeom_area`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/liblwgeom/lwgeom.c#L1599) which eventually calls [`lwcurvepoly_area`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/liblwgeom/lwcurvepoly.c#L139). And there again we see it with it's 32-sides.

```
/**
 * This should be rewritten to make use of the curve itself.
 */
double
lwcurvepoly_area(const LWCURVEPOLY *curvepoly)
{
    double area = 0.0;
    LWPOLY *poly;
    if( lwgeom_is_empty((LWGEOM*)curvepoly) )
        return 0.0;
    poly = lwcurvepoly_stroke(curvepoly, 32);
```